# Deploy updated Git files to the ftp

Tags: git, sublimetext3, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, filezilla

Is there a way to update almost automatically *(or with a simple click)* the FTP files of my site every time my master branch is updated?. Currently I am using the next tools in my pipeline:

**Sumblime Text:** as my code editor.

**Gitlab:** as my git server.

**SourceTree:** as my git client, *(from here I checkout, merge and manage my branches)*

**FileZilla:** as my ftp client.

I just would like to know an easy to implement way to update just the changes and new files *(code, images, files, folders)* to my **ftp**.

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/767380/on-git-push-to-one-server-also-pull-the-pushed-files-using-ftp